# Python 3: Pulling specific data from documents

Tags: python

I am new to python and using it for my internship. My goal is to pull specific data from about 100 .ls documents (all in the same folder) and then write it to another .txt file and from there import it into excel. My problem is I can read all the files, but cannot figure out how to pull the specifics from that file into a list. From the list I want to write them into a .txt file and then import to excel.

Is there anyway to read set readlines() to only capture certain lines?

Comment: I think readlines() does not know what the line contains beforehand so the only way is to read the line and if it contains something you want then  keep it, otherwise move on to the next line

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what you want without an example or sample code/content. What you might do is create a list and append the desired line to it.

```
result_list = [] # Create an empty list

with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    Lines = f.readlines() # read the lines of the file

for line in Lines: # loop through the lines
    if "desired_string" in line:
        result_list.append(line) # if the line contains the string, the line is added
```

Comment: I have got the the readlines part down. Now I am stuck on taking that data and using it to populate a list? What is the best way to go about that?

Comment: That is what the  result_list.append(line) does, it takes the line and appends it to the list.